# How to play both mp4 and hls videos in angular 7?

Tags: angular, angular7

I am going to develop a media application using angular 7. I want to play m3u8 (for live streaming) as well as mp4 video url. What will be the option to play these URLs using angular 7.

I have used mat-video component but it only plays mp4 video and i want to play m3u8 video too. So please suggest relevant component/module and URL to run videos using angular 7.

I have used mat-video for playing video. code is as follows:

```
 <mat-video [autoplay]="true" [preload]="true" [fullscreen]="true" [download]="false" [quality]="false" spinner="spin" poster="{{subcategories.media[video_id].thumbnail_url}}" src="{{subcategories.media[video_id].videoUrl[0]}}">
 </mat-video>
```

Comment: Post the code, what you have tried!

Comment: i have updated the code, please review

Comment: Its depressing to see no answers to this question since 1 year 8 months.

Comment: use video.js plugin